# C++ find words with first and last same letter and sort them in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, class, sorting, object

i can't make program that reads from file words ( there is no limit of words or length to them ) with same first letter and last. I use class and object and first of all i can't make reading them

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
class Texts{

public:
    void Realding(string &All);
    void Searching(string &text, char *Word);
};
int main()
{

    Texts A;
    string Text; char word[40];
    A.Reading(Text);
    A.Searching(Text, word);
    system("PAUSE");


}

void Texts::Reading(string &All)
{
    string temp;
    ifstream read("Text.txt");
    while (getline(read, temp)) { All += temp; All += "\n"; }
    cout << All;

}

void Texts::Searching(string &text, char *Word)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int letters = 0;
    int zodz = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (1)
    {

        if (text[i] == ' ' || text[i] == '\0')
        {

            zodz++;
            if (text[0] == text[i - 1])
            {
                letters = j;
                for (int l = 0; l < letters; l++)
                {
                    //cout << text[l];
                }
                j = 0;
            }
            if (text[i + 1 - j] == text[i - 1])
            {
                letters = j;
                for (int l = i - j; l < letters; l++)
                {
                //  cout << text[l];
                }
                j = 0;
            }


        }

        if (text[i] == '\0') break;   
        else
        i++;                           
        j++;

    }
}
```

I can't make it properly read from file... Text.txt looks like

```
asdfa su egze hah ktis faf
```

And how later when selected words with first and last same letter to assign to array, that later to sort them in alphabetical order. Thanks if someone helps me.

Comment: Is there a requirement to use a class?  I suggest you perform this in the `main` function or another freestanding function.  It could help you out.

Comment: This code does not compile; I doubt that this is your real code. If you don't show us your real code, it's difficult for us to help you.

Comment: You should process one word at a time; don't read them all into a single string.

Comment: There is requirement. Oh sorry, yeah there functions "Reading" ant "Searching".  This is real code. I will change functions

Answer (score 0):

Reading from file:

```
std::ifstream in(NameOfFile);
std::string word;

while (in >> word) //will stop when word can't be read. probably bad file or end of file
{
    // do something with word
}
```

Find word with same first and last letter

```
if (word.front() == word.back())
{
    // do something with word
}
```

Note this does not handle words with capitalized letters. It would not find "Mom". It will likely crash over empty words. Both have trivial fixes.

Assign word to array

```
array[index++] == word;
```

This assumes you want to advance the index after inserting into the array. Please note the program will behave poorly if the array is overfilled. If you are allowed to by the assignment, please consider using a `std::vector`.

Sorting the array

```
std::sort(array, array + index);
```

This assumes you are allowed to use `std::sort`. Again, if possible use a `std::vector` in place of the array. `index` is assumed to be the value of index from the adding example above after all of the adding has been done. If you are NOT allowed to use `std::sort` ask another question. It's a lengthy topic.

Comment: `if (word.front() == word.back())` might be a little clearer.